# How can I prevent going to another page when the user enters the wrong email and password?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

This is the response of the statusCode and body if the user enters the wrong email and password. `I/flutter (20074): 200 I/flutter (20074): {"code":1,"message":"invalid username or password","data":null}` and if user enter a correct email and password this is the response `I/flutter (20074): {"code":0,"message":"success","data":{"Id":121106,"Name":"User 1","Email":"user@gmail.com","Token":"2db0ce86-2dc0-4381-97de-ce6e0c341d90"}}`. I want to validate my login if the user enters the wrong email and password. It will display "Invalid credentials" and it will not go to another page. That's the response of the Sample Rest Api Url For Testing With Authentication on the internet.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('profile_image.jpg', height: 150, width: 150,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Email",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                          // onChanged: (val){
                          //   validateEmail(val);
                          // },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: passController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Password",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    OutlinedButton.icon(onPressed: () {
                      login();
                    }, icon: const Icon(Icons.login, size: 18,), label: const Text("Login")),
                  ],
                )
             )
          ),
       ),
    );
 }
```

create function to call login post api

```
Future<void> login() async {
    if(emailController.text.isNotEmpty && passController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var headers =  {"Content-type": "application/json"};
      var myBody = {
        'email' : emailController.text,
        'password' : passController.text,
      };
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("url"),
          headers: headers,
          body: jsonEncode( myBody ));
      
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()));
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Credentials.")));
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Blank Field Not Allowed")));
    }
  }
```

Comment: if both responses have status code of 200, just check ```code``` or whatever field is defined for that purpose.

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check for both status code and body of the response:

```
  if(response.statusCode == 200 && response.body['code'] == 0) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()));
  } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Credentials.")));
  }
```

Comment: It should be`response.body['code'] == 0` instead, right?

Comment: @beckzile  oh, my bad. yes you're right . thank you for mentioning that. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Xoltawn this is not working I got an error with ```code``` inside the bracket. The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Comment: @LovePeople what about ```response.body['code'] == "0" ```?

Comment: ```final data = jsonDecode(response.body); if(response.statusCode == 200 && data['code'] == 0)```. I try this one and solved the problem.